# Reclassify attributes that are less than x% of total as 'other'

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Okay so I have data as so:

```
ID      Name  Job
001     Bill  Carpenter
002    Wilma  Lawyer
003  Greyson  Lawyer
004    Eddie  Janitor
```

I want to group these together for analysis so any job that appears less than **x** percent of the whole will be grouped into "Other"

How can I do this, here is what I tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Job) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(count)) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

And now I know what the percentages are but how do I integrate this in to the original data to make everything below **X** "Other". (let's say less than or equal to 25% is other).

Maybe there's a more straightforward way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Job) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n)) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'Job') %>%
  mutate(Job = replace(Job, n <= 0.25, 'Other'))
```

To integrate our calculation in original data we do a `left_join` and then `replace` the values.